# Connect to AWS private subnet without static IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, cloud

My ISP user CGNAT and I don't have a static IP address but I want to connect to my AWS subnet. I tried creating a VM for an OpenVPN server but that way I can only connect to the server VM unless I setup the on all the other VMs. How can I connect to my subnet without a static IP address?

Comment: I would think that wireguard might be a good fit here, though I admit I haven't tested this particular combination.

Comment: It still has the issue of installing the VPN on all the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with OpenVPN, but, with a simple wireguard setup, you can have a single wireguard server which can allow access to any number of private subnets.

In this example, `10.xx.xx.x` are my private subnets, and `192.168.x.x` is my wireguard network.

1. Pick or set up a dedicated machine as the wireguard server and set up a basic configuration. E.g. server side

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.200.1
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer] # Enes home computer
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.200.2
```

and client side

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 192.168.200.2
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = your.wg.server
AllowedIPs = 192.168.200.1/32, 10.0.0.0/8  # We can route whatever we want!
```

2. Configure the wireguard server to allow ip forwarding, with e.g. sysctl settings:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

3. Configure the wireguard server to allow masquerading, e.g. with firewalld, a custom rule on the zone where the wireguard interface is (e.g. internal)

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.211.0/24" masquerade' --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

And that should be it. Use `wg` to verify that wireguard is working and you should be able to ping any `10.x.x.x` address that the wireguard server can.

I run this setup with a single wireguard server VM against dozens of private subnets with hundreds of machines.